# Why we need public render parameters in jsr286

Tags: event-handling, jsr286

I am trying to udnerstand the concept of public render paramter in jsr286 portlets.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpexpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.exp.doc_v6101/dev/pltcom_pubrndrprm.html

Now inter portlet communication can happen like this:Portlet 1 publishes an event, Portlet 2 processes it and generates a response and puts it in session scope. So now portlet 1 can see it also since both portlets share same session object. So what is the purpose of public render parameters as a way of sharing information between portlets?

Answer (score 2):

Both have there advantages. Generally Public render parameters are lightweight communication. Following are some of the important features of both.

**Public render parameters:**

- They are limited to simple string values.
- They do not require explicit administration to set up coordination.
- They cause no performance overhead as the number of portlets sharing
  information grows.
- They can be set from links encoded in portal themes and skins.

**Portlet events:**

- They can contain complex information.
- They allow fine-grained control by setting up different sorts of
  wires between portlets (on-page or cross-page, public or private).
- They can trigger cascaded updates with different information. For
  example, portlet A can send event X to portlet B, which in turn sends
  a different event Y to portlet C.
- They cause increasing processing overhead as the number of
  communication links grows.